# Abusing the VirtualBox VM GUI for non-Oracle Linux machines

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

The current version of VirtualBox is able to display not only local, but also
remote VMs if they are running in the Oracle cloud.

Is ist possible to abuse this feature to **display Linux VMs running on other virtualizers**  or **display non-virtual Linux Desktops** running on real hardware ?
This could be done by installing the software needed to talk the VRDP protocol in the Linux system itself instead of in the virtualization layer (outside the VM) as it is done in the Oracle cloud.

I'd like to do that in order to use the GUI features that VirtualBox provides:
For me, the most important feature is the ability to press the RightCtrl key
to switch processing of special keys between the local (Windows) OS and the VM.

This feature is missing in other remote desktop programs for Windows which use the VNC or RDP protocols.